# Eclipse Syntax error insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

While I'm modding Minecraft, Eclipse said to me that I'm doing something wrong with the Creative Tabs.

Here is my Code:

```
//I don´t write all imports in here

@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.NAME, version = Reference.VERSION, acceptedMinecraftVersions = Reference.ACCEPTED_VERSIONS)
public class BetterLife {

    @Instance
    public static BetterLife instance;

    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Reference.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Reference.SERVER_PROXY_CLASS)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event){
        ModItems.init();
        ModItems.register();

        ModBlocks.init();
        ModBlocks.register();
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void Init(FMLInitializationEvent event){
        proxy.init();
        ModCrafting.register();
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event){

    }

    public static CreativeTabs tabBetterLife = new CreativeTab("tab_betterlife") {

        @Override
        public ItemStack getTabIcon() {
            return ItemStack(ModItems.ruby);
        }
    }//Here eclipse comes:"Syntax error Insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration"

}
```

I don´t know what eclipse want. Because adding or/and removing ";" doesn't matter.
If I insert ";" then eclipse say that the complete method is wrong.

I hope you can understand my bad english ;)

Comment: What's the exact error when you add `;`?

Comment: @shmosel I assume the `ItemStack` return statement.

Comment: Did you add the `;` and then try to compile. Maybe eclispe is just a bit slow at telling you the error is fixed.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: how about `return new ItemStack(ModItems.ruby);` (note the "**new**")

Comment: It isnt an error of eclipse.. minecraft crashes immediately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The semicolon is needed to create the static field `tabBetterLife`.
2. The method `getTabIcon` missed a `new` for its return value.

   ```
   public static CreativeTabs tabBetterLife =
       new CreativeTab("tab_betterlife") {

       @Override
       public ItemStack getTabIcon() {
           return new ItemStack(ModItems.ruby);
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: Ok, i tried that out. With the "new" it creates nevertheless two errors: 1st:Multiple markers at this line
 - CreativeTab cannot be resolved to a type
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from new CreativeTab(){} to Creative Tabs //This error is in the first line you wrote. The second error:The method getTabIcon() of type new CreativeTab(){} must override or implement a supertype method // this error are at the "public item stack" line. And all characters are red underlined.

Comment: @TillW. remove the 's' at the end of `public static CreativeTab`, The `CreativeTabs` class is equivalent to the Blocks class (that is, a reference class: eg. `Blocks.DIRT`).  It is not the same as the `CreativeTab` class.

Comment: Ok. Thak you all. I found out that i had to write public ItemStack getTabIconItem(){ so one error gone. But their is still existing another erro. When is write public static CreativeTab oder Creative Tabs eclipse say Multiple markers at this line
 - CreativeTabs cannot be resolved 
  to a type or Multiple markers at this line
 - CreativeTab cannot be resolved 
  to a type. So with "s" or not these error still exists.